# Using Constructor to initialize ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to initialize values of ArrayList ar to ArrayList x using the constructor. Is the way I have done it wrong? If so how can I do it?

```
public Class Sensor {
   ArrayList<float> x= new ArrayList<float>();
   public Sensor(ArrayList<float> ar)
   {
        this.x=ar; 
   }

}
```

Comment: Your indentation is terrible, you have named your class like a method, you aren't creating a deep copy (not sure if you wanted to), you should program to an interface instead of the concrete `ArrayList` type and finally you have used raw types. **tl;dr** Define *wrong*?

Comment: Don't use raw types.  Other than that, no *real* complaints...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it, ArrayList x is already initialized. You should just 
declare the variable and then initialize it in your constructor by setting 
ar equal to x.

```
public class ReadData<T> {

private List<T> x;

public ReadData(List<T> ar)
{
        this.x=ar; 
}

}
```

PS: corrected the naming convention of Class. Should start with capital.

Comment: **Please** don't use [raw types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). Also, please prefer programming to the `List` interface. And consider making `ReadData` generic (or mentioning the possibility).

Comment: thanx. I didn't know anything about using raw types earlier.